# Testing Akka PubSub mediator with specs2

Tags: scala, akka, publish-subscribe, specs2

I'm fairly new to testing Akka and have been stuck trying to simply verify that a message is sent to a subscriber when a publish message is sent to an Akka mediator from `akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubMediator`.  I'd like to understand how to get his working before I branch into verifying actual business logic.

```
import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, Actor }
import akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubExtension
import akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubMediator.{ Subscribe, Publish }
import akka.testkit.{ ImplicitSender, TestKit }
import org.specs2.mutable.{ After, Specification }
import queues.{ Publisher, Subscriber }   
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class PubSubActorSupport extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PubSubTest")) with ImplicitSender with After { 
  override def after = system.shutdown()   
  lazy val subscriberRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Subscriber]))
  lazy val publisherRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Publisher]))
  lazy val testActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyTestActor]))    
}

class MyTestActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = { case x => () }
}

object EventsTest extends Specification {
  "Publish/Subscriber Actors" should {
    "work" in new PubSubActorSupport {
      subscriberRef ! ("topic", testActorRef)
      publisherRef ! ("topic", "Hello!")

      // assert that MyTestActor received "Hello!" from the publisher actor
      expectMsg(500 milli, "Hello!")
    }
  }
}
```

I figure I'm not using `expectMsg` correctly.  My Subscriber/Publisher actors are below.

```
trait Mediator extends Actor {
  val mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension(context.system).mediator
}

class Publisher extends Mediator {
  def receive = {
    case (topic: String, msg: Any) => mediator ! Publish(topic, msg)
  }
}

class Subscriber extends Mediator {
  def receive = {
    case (topic: String, ref: ActorRef) => mediator ! Subscribe(topic, ref)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific test suite, but I'd say that you have no link from your "MyTestActor" to your expectMsg. In other words, your actor is probably receiving the message, but doing nothing on it, while expectMsg expect to receive a message in the test, rather than in the instance of your actor. But I may be far off. A quick test to check this would be to modify ryour MyTestActor receive method to do a println of whatever if receives. If you find it in the output you know that's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Check this sample for testing SubPub pattern

https://github.com/JAVEO/clustered-chat/blob/master/test/actors/UserSocketSpec.scala

expectMsg just verify message that is send to "sender". And if you want to verify a message sent to a subscribers, write like this (From the sample above)

```
val mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension(system).mediator
val chatMember1 = TestProbe()
mediator ! Subscribe(topic, chatMember1.ref)

//... Call the publisher to publish message

chatMember1.expectMsg(ChatMessage(UserId, message))
```

Comment: In the last version of Akka (2.4.14) you have to use DistributedPubSub instead of DistributedPubSubExtension